# How to suppress prompt table validation

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

Is there a way to suppress field prompt table validation for a particular value using peoplecode.

For example:
On the page, for field A I enter value as "NEXT" (this value doesnot exist in the prompt table attached). When I save the page, if the value entered is "NEXT" I want the page to be saved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: I want to use the prompt with edit but only when the field value is "NEXT" it should not validate.

Comment: You could make the prompt table be a view which does a `union` of your actual prompt table combined with the value "NEXT"

Comment: Thanks Ben! Is it possible to do the same using peoplecode?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to do precisely what you're asking for.  Once you assign a prompt table to a field, I don't think you can remove the prompt table validation.  The closest thing I know of is using a dynamic prompt table, like this https://peoplesoftconcept.blogspot.com/2014/01/creating-dynamic-prompt-using-dynamic-view-in-peoplesoft.html

Comment: You can add a button that will SET the NEXT value through peoplecode.... if you do that, I think this will bypass the TableEdit

Answer (score 0):

Remove the prompt table from the field on the record. 
Write a function that checks the value of field A and checks the table you were using as a prompt only if the value is not NEXT and add it to the fieldedit event.